# Specify color in catplot

Tags: python, seaborn, swarmplot, catplot

I would like to specify the color of particular observations using seaborn catplot. In a made up exemple:

```
import seaborn as sns
import random as r

name_list=['pepe','Fabrice','jim','Michael']
country_list=['spain','France','uk','Uruguay']
favourite_color=['green','blue','red','white']

df=pd.DataFrame({'name':[r.choice(name_list) for n in range(100)],
             'country':[r.choice(country_list) for n in range(100)],
             'fav_color':[r.choice(favourite_color) for n in range(100)],
             'score':np.random.rand(100),
            })

sns.catplot(x='fav_color',
           y='score',
           col='country',
           col_wrap=2,
           data=df,
           kind='swarm')
```

I would like to colour (or mark in another distinctive way, it could be the marker) all the observations with the name 'pepe'. How I could do that ? The other colors I dont mind, it would be better if they are all the same.

[image: catplot exemple]

Comment: Seaborn lacks a bit of flexibility here. So I would guess you cannot do it with a `catplot`. However using a FacetGrid and mapping customized swarmplots to it might work. I.e. using a function that plots two swarmplots per plot, one with all data and another one with only the "pepe" data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the results you want by adding a boolean column to the dataframe and using it as the `hue` parameter of the `catplot()` call. This way you will obtain the results with two colours (one for `pepe` observations and one for the rest). Results can be seen here:

[image]

Also, the parameter `legend=False` should be set since otherwise the legend for `is_pepe` will appear on the side.

The code would be as below:

```py
df['is_pepe'] = df['name'] == 'pepe'

ax  = sns.catplot(x='fav_color',
                  y='score',
                  col='country',
                  col_wrap=2,
                  data=df,
                  kind='swarm',
                  hue='is_pepe',
                  legend=False)
```

Furthermore, you can specify the two colours you want for the two kinds of observations (pepe and not-pepe) using the parameter `palette` and the top-level function `sns.color_palette()` as shown below:

```py
ax  = sns.catplot(x='fav_color',
                  y='score',
                  col='country',
                  col_wrap=2,
                  data=df,
                  kind='swarm',
                  hue='is_pepe',
                  legend=False,
                  palette=sns.color_palette(['green', 'blue']))
```

Obtaining this results:

[image]