# can you highlight specific observations in categorical scatter plot in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot, categorical-data, plot-annotations

I have 8 categories and I already plotted categorical scatter plot with sns.catplot. Is there a way to highlight a specific observation(s) in each category to compare the positions with respect to other observations?

Comment: I think this is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772467/specify-color-in-seaborn-catplot but since I have too many observations, the observation color is not recognizable. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use text annotations, using the `annotate` method on the `ax` (`matplotlib.axes.Axes`) attribute of the `FaceGrid` object returned by `seaborn.catplot`. For example, the code below annotates the observations that are greater than .5 on a normal sample by using Boolean selection in the dataframe, `df[df.y > .5]`, and `df.apply(...)` will annotate all points.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': range(10), 'y':np.random.normal(0,1,size=10)})
df['odd'] = df.x.apply(lambda x: x % 2)

g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='odd')

df[df.y > .5].apply(lambda p: g.ax.annotate(f'({p.x}, {round(p.y, 2)})', (p.x, p.y)), axis=1)
```

[image]

You can see more details on the `annotate` method [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate).